# Meaning of '계산이 떨어진다'

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idiom

I'd like to know the meaning of 계산이 떨어지다 in '여기에 왜 터를 잡으셨는지 계산이 떨어지는데'. To me, it looks like 'the calculation/reasoning has dropped' which I'm interpreting to mean something similar to 'the penny has dropped' in English i.e. something is finally understood after a long time of trying to comprehend/understand it. Please could somebody explain to me what 계산이 떨어지다 means? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [`떨어지다`](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/dicSearch/SearchView?ParaWordNo=89796) sounds like an abbreviation of [`맞아떨어지다`](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=57165). Its literal meaning is `math (or size/number) is correct`. It can also mean to `add up`, `figure out`, `make clear` or `make sense`.

So in your given context `계산이 떨어지는데` would translate to `Oh, I can imagine why you did ...`(why you chose this place).

---

`계산이 떨어진다`는 말은 `산수가 꼭 들어맞는다`는 뜻이고 예문에서는 `예상이 된다`, `어떤 생각이 들었다`는 뜻으로 쓰였습니다.

예시:

- 수지가 맞다
- 수지타산이 맞아떨어진다
- 계산이 맞아떨어진다
- 계산이 떨어진다

---

## [떨어지다](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=89796)

동사 Verb

25. be clearly divided without a remainder

- 나눗셈에서 나머지가 없이 나누어지다.
- For a certain figure to be divided without a remainder in division.

> - 계산이 떨어지다.
> - 셈이 떨어지다.
> - 수가 떨어지다.
> - 맞게 떨어지다.
> - 계산을 잘못했는지 셈이 맞게 떨어지지 않는다.

---

## [맞아떨어지다](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=57165)

동사 Verb

1. be accurate

- 조금의 틀림도 없이 꼭 맞다.
- To be accurate without a discrepancy.

> - 계산이 맞아떨어지다.
> - 예상이 맞아떨어지다.
> - 장면이 잘 맞아떨어지다.
> - 딱 맞아떨어지다.
> - 실제와 꼭 맞아떨어지다.
> - 영화의 결말이 관객의 예상과 맞아떨어지면 관객은 만족감을 느낀다.
> - 판매 전략이 소비자 성향과 딱 맞아떨어지면서 매출액이 증가하였다.
> - 김 대표가 받은 비자금과 통장에 찍힌 금액의 액수가 꼭 맞아떨어진다.
> - 어머니는 하늘의 뜻과 땅의 기운이 잘 맞아떨어져야 좋은 일이 생긴다고 하셨다.

2. be in harmony

- 가락이나 호흡 등이 잘 어울려 조화를 이루다.
- For tunes, teamwork, etc., to be good together and become well harmonized.

> - 딱 맞아떨어진 반주.
> - 노래가 장단과 멋지게 맞아떨어지다.
> - 박자가 잘 맞아떨어지다.
> - 배우들의 호흡이 맞아떨어지다.
> - 기가 막히게 맞아떨어지다.
> - 슬픈 피아노 선율과 영화의 장면이 기막히게 맞아떨어졌다.
> - 영화를 촬영할 때 배우들의 호흡이 잘 맞아떨어져 멋진 장면이 나왔다.

---